# ERROR in ../node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/ckbutton. directive.d.TS: 1:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'ckeditor'

Tags: node.js, angular, ckeditor, node-modules

In the Angular project, I got this error msg ( ERROR in ../node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/ckbutton. directive.d.TS: 1:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'ckeditor'.)
what is the reason for this error msg ?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that you have not installed @types/ckeditor package in your project.

Installing this package should resolve this error.
If it still persists, then let me know.

Comment: now I have installed @type/CKEditor, maximum errors have been fixed but now I got this error:
ERROR in ../node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/ckeditor.component.d.ts:36:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

36     get value(): string;
           ~~~~~
../node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/ckeditor.component.d.ts:37:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

37     set value(v: string);

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by removing `^` from dependency version. I replaced `^1.2.9` with `1.2.9`.

[image]

**Note: I'm using Angular version 10.0.2**